# Getting Synergy+ to work with Windows 7 64bit and Windows XP 32bit?

Tags: windows, synergy

My Windows XP box is Dell 4550 dimension. Windows 7 box is Home Premium. Synergy + installs fine on the Windows  7box, but using Windows  xp as the client, it won't work? Do I need to disconnect the vga connection from my monitor and control entirely from the win7 dvi connection?

In setting up ( links ) on Windows 7 as the server, I have NO way of inputing info? The setup on the Windows xp box is simple and does so OK, but I can't connect to the Windows xp box!

It must be the vga connection on the Windows XP box. In order to use both machines, I have to turn one off and the other on. Hence-the VGA is needed on Windows XP. Any info/help most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A few questions - what version of Synergy?  I would strongly suggest you use 1.4.2 as it has a GUI for setting up the connections and it much easier.

Have you checked your network - i.e. can the machine ping each other?  Has your firewall been told to trust Synergy?  Have you opened port 24800? (Not always required, depends on your firewall behaviour).

You need one running as the Server, and that's the one where you should use the GUI to set things up ("XP is left of Win7" for example).

On the other, simply run Synergy as a client and connect to the server.
I am not sure what VGA has to do with it, both computers need to be able to display video so you can see what you are doing!

Answer (score 1):

Finally got things working! On the XP machine I had forgotten what the machine name was. Using IPs for both machines simply wouldn't work, hence: The correct machine names were needed.

My next adventure is getting sound to play on the client. From what I've read here, it's not going to work.

Synergy works for what I need.